# Most efficient (speed) way to run hash and filter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that opens a text file and hashes the line. Then filters it by getting the first 4 strings of the hash and opening it as a file. What are some optimization techniques I can use to improve the speed of this script?

Code:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import hashlib
folder_path = "Folder\\"
folder_dir = os.listdir(folder_path)
for folder in folder_dir: # for every folder inside this folder_dir
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path + folder): # for every file inside folder
        r=open(folder_path+folder+"\\"+file,"r+",encoding="ISO-8859-1") # open the file as r
        for line in r: # for every line in r
            if ":" in line: #if the line contains ":", ";", or " ", split the line
                split_line = line.split(":")
            elif ";" in line:
                split_line = line.split(";")
            elif " " in line:
                split_line = line.split(" ")
            else:
                pass
            final_line = split_line[1] # define the split line
            hash = hashlib.md5(final_line.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() # hash the final_line
            w=open("HashDB\\" + hash[:4] + ".txt","a",encoding="ISO-8859-1").write(hash + ":" + final_line) # open the first 4 letters/numbers of the file and write the hash with the line along with it.
```

Comment: What's telling you this is slow? Did you profile it, or are you just imagining that it's inefficient? The first immediate problem I see is that you're opening file handles in a loop and never closing them, so this code is going to crash after some number of iterations.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has become such a dire standard warning.  Although there ARE Python installations where they are deferred, in normal CPython the file is closed as soon as the handle goes out of scope.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I was just curious if there were any ways to optimize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lines only have one of ":; " I'd maybe do this:

```
def split(line):
  for c in ":; ":
    try:
      return line.split(c)[1], True
    except:
      pass
  return line, False
```

Multiprocessing:
I'd move all of your code into a function then spawn workers using multiprocessing

So your function looks like this:

```
def process(input_dir, file):
  with open(os.path.join(input_dir, file),"r+", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
      result, processed = split(line)
      if not processed: continue
      hash = hashlib.md5(result.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
      with open(os.path.join(HASH_DB, f"{hash[:4]}.txt", "a", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as outFile
        outFile.write(f"{hash}:result")
```

Spawn the workers:

```
POOL_COUNT = 10
HASH_DB = "./"

folder_path = "Folder\\"
folder_dir = os.listdir(folder_path)

for folder in folder_dir:
  pool = []
  for file in os.listdir(folder_path + folder):
      if len(pool) == POOL_COUNT:
        for p in pool: p.start()
        for p in pool: p.join()
        pool = []
      pool.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(folder, file))

# cleanup if there are any un-run processes
if len(pool):
  for p in pool: p.start()
  for p in pool: p.join()
  pool = []
```

I haven't tested any of this, but it should be a good starting point